# Jquery-form-validator validate format date in datepicker

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, datepicker

I have form with input with date picker and I try to validate format date like `"yyyy-mm-dd"` when changed data in input. I install `jquery-form-validator` and write like this

```
<form id="filter-form" action="my action" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_datepicker" dataformatas="dd-mm-yyyy" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filterForm = $('#filter-form');

  filterForm.validate({
    rules: {
      from_datepicker: {
        required: true,
        date: true
      }
    }
  });

  $('#to_datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    showAnim: "drop",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showWeek: true
  });

$('.hasDatepicker').on('change', function () {
    filterForm.submit()
});
```

Then I try to write in input some data like `11111` but and `jquery-form-validator` is not called. How do I use this plugin?

Comment: is datepicker showing? Means when you click on input field, atleast it is showing you datepicker?

Comment: yes, I can put in date picker some data, like `1111`

Comment: That means your datepicker jquery not working, it should display datepicker when you just click on it. Check my answer which i have posted.

Comment: no, when I clicked to input, datepicker is showing but I can keyup another format date, like dd/mm/yy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate date with jquery validation plugin then make sure you have included this js file inside your head tag.

This js is needed when you are using additional methods.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Also make sure you have also included validation min file which is must whenever you are working with jquery validation plugin:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Also, in your code i can see, your element name is to_date and in your validation you have put from_datepicker.

So, also put the name which you want to validate. If you want to validate to_date then your validation code should be:

```
var filterForm = $('#filter-form');
filterForm.validate({
    rules: {
      to_date: {
        required: true,
        date: true
     },
    messages:{
       to_date:{
         required: "Date is required",
         date:"enter date only"
       }
    }
   }
});
```

Comment: I have console error `additional-methods.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined`

Comment: have you included this validation min file: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: I added `js/form-validator/jquery.form-validator.min.js`

Comment: Can you please try the live js urls? I have mentioned both urls in my answer.

Comment: Make sure you first add validation min file then additional method js file.

Comment: yaa. it should.

Comment: ok, I got validation error after submit. But I need validate input like on change event and I want understand how to use exist validation message from plugin with different language

Comment: and I want validate format date field, I need validate error after user enters wrong format. like `222333`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163864/discussion-between-hetal-chauhan-and-shuba-ivan).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to validate date. Make that input field readonly.

To display date picker:

Put below code inside your head tag.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> <!--do not include this jquery min file if it is already there, otherwise it may conflict-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( function() {
  $( "#to_datepicker" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      showAnim: "drop",
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showWeek: true
  });
});
</script>
```

And put readonly attribute with your input tag like this:

```
<input type="text" name="to_date" id="to_datepicker" dataformatas="dd-mm-yyyy" data-validation-format="yyyy-mm-dd" readonly >
```